# My MBP freeze on a Back-Up after having installed a SSD

Tags: ssd

I'm having a MBP (mid 2012, 13 inches), and I changed my HDD for a Samsung V-Nand SSD 850 EVO. I had created a back-up with my External G-drive. Now, the screen freeze since a good while.

[image]

**Question :** What do I have to do to fix this problem?

Comment: Try force restarting the computer. Hold he power button down for ten seconds. Then wait ten more. Then press the power button again and see if it boots up

Comment: When you changed your drive, did you install a fresh copy of OS X or restore from backup?

Answer (score 1):

Try to macOS Recovery from Internet.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314

With a LAN cable/ WiFi.

Comment: To make the answer better, summarize the steps need to launch Internet Recovery. Apples links are notorious for going stale.  If you summarize here and the link goes stale, the answer is still good.